# Unable to run gradle tests using gitlab and docker-compose

Tags: gradle, docker-compose, gitlab-ci

I want to run tests using Gradle after docker-compose up (Postgres DB + Spring-Boot app). All flow must be running inside the Gitlab merge request step. The problem is when I was running my test using the script part in gitlab-ci file. Important, in such a situation, we are in the correct directory where GitLab got my project. Part of **gitlab-ci** file:

```
before_script:
    - ./gradlew clean build
    - cp x.jar /path/x.jar
    - docker-compose -f /path/docker-compose.yaml up -d
script:
    - ./gradlew :functional-tests:clean test -Penv=gitlab --info
```

But here I can't call http://localhost:8080 -> connection refused. I try put 0.0.0.0 or 172.17.0.3 or docker.host... etc insite tests config, but it didn't work.

So, I made insite docker-compose another container where I try to run my test using the entry point command. To do that, I must have the current GitLab directory, but can't mount them.

My current solution:
**Gitlab-ci:**

```
run-functional-tests:
  stage: run_functional_tests
  image:
    name: 'xxxx/docker-compose-java-11:0.0.7'
  script:
    - ./gradlew clean build -x test
    - 'export SHARED_PATH="$(dirname ${CI_PROJECT_DIR})"' // current gitlab worspace dir
    - cp $CI_PROJECT_DIR/x.jar $CI_PROJECT_DIR/docker/gitlab/x.jar
    - docker-compose -f $CI_PROJECT_DIR/docker/gitlab/docker-compose.yaml up -d
    - docker-compose -f $CI_PROJECT_DIR/docker/gitlab/docker-compose.yaml logs -f
  timeout: 30m
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    build:
      context: ../postgres
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    networks:
      - app-postgres
    ports:
      - 5432
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    container_name: app
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - app-postgres
  functional-tests:
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: app-functional-tests
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ${SHARED_PATH}:/app
    depends_on:
      - app
    entrypoint: ["bash", "-c", "sleep 20 && ./gradlew :functional-tests:clean test -Penv=gitlab --info"]
    networks:
      - app-postgres
networks:
  app-postgres:
```

but in such a situation my working_dir - `/app` - is empty. Can someone assist with that?

Comment: Can you double check if SHARED_PATH is coming through to the `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: Also can try copying the `/app` directory in the Dockerfile instead of binding the volume?

Comment: hey @JasonS, yes, functional-tests container see this variable SHARED_PATH. Call `echo $SHARED_PATH` inside entrypoint. When I change Dockerfile and add `ADD "${SHARED_PATH}" /app` I got only project_name_dir/docker/gitlab folders structure, but last, GitLab is empty. But have not other project files including build.gradle...

Comment: Can we see your Dockerfile?

Comment: I fix the problem using `- docker-compose build --no-cache` before `up`